# OpenGL: How would I implement texture arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, textures, pyopengl

I am trying to make a cube and texture each of it's sides differently. After a bit of research I found out that texture arrays are the way to go, but I have no idea how to implement them. I've seen https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture , but that didn't help. Could someone explain texture arrays to me?

Comment: I realize now that the link is on array textures, not texture arrays. I still can't find anything on texture arrays.

Comment: Anyway you should use array textures. Don't use texture sampler arrays. If you would use texture sampler arrays then you would have to use a different texture unit for each texture in the array. Hence you are limited to the number of texture units (in worst case the number is 8). If you use a [`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)), then you can specify the parts by [`glTexSubImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml) and you have to specify 3 dimensional texture coordinates.